# Drush documentation

Tags: 8, drush

I'm curious if anyone else noticed how difficult it is to get drush working based on the available documentation? Drush is a great command line tool, and it's a pity that the **official drush install docs page** doesn't bubble to the top in Google searches.

I realize that we're a community powered project, so there's paid staff. Nevertheless, it seems we've overlooked some of the edge cases, such as 'installing Drush after the fact,' 'adding drush to the .bashrc file' and/or 'what if you're installing onto Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP7.1' scenario.

I realize that with the sheer number of available options out there (Mac, Ubuntu 14, 16.04, 18.04, CentOS, Red Hat, Postgresql, MySQL, Mariadb, virtual machines, etc. ad infinitum) there may simply be too many edge cases to account for every possible situation -- it just (anecdotally) seems to me that it's always a non-simple task to install and then run drush.

Is there someone I can send $10 to?

NOTE: I'm fully mentally preparing for my question to be flagged for deletion for not being general enough / specific enough, off topic, too short, too long, not enough reputation points, etc. I am posting this on SE after, all, right?  ;)

Comment: Did you try http://www.drush.org?

Comment: When I google the suggested phrase from the question, I get the links from my answer as the top results.

Comment: Are you aware that Google lists different results for different people based on prior searches, geographic location, etc? However, if you search for Benjamin Franklin, the Wikipedia result will almost always be 1 or 2. So, there's something weird happening here, as to why it's in the 5th or 7th place rather than at the top. Just an observation.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit the [Drush project on GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops), the first link in the Resources section points to the [Installation documentation](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/). This same link also appears front-and-center on drush.org.  This installation page is for Drush 9. If you don't want Drush 9, there is a link to the Drush 8 documentation on the top of the Drush 9 installation page.

The recommended way to install Drush 9 is as a site-local install as part of the drupal-composer/drupal-project. If you use this project, Drush is automatically installed (along with Drupal Console).

The recommended way to install Drush 8 is to download the phar from GitHub.

It is a non-goal of the Drush project to attempt to enumerate all of the possible installation methods for Drush. If you stick with the recommended methods, then you should have an easy enough time. If you have any suggestions on how to improve the documentation for the recommended installation methods, please submit a pull request.

The Drush maintainers have never attempted to collect donations because most people's idea of a reasonable value for Drush is so low that it seems unlikely that any such efforts would recoup the cost to collect it. Instead of your cash, please contribute to the project, or hire a contractor to contribute to the project if you cannot contribute directly yourself.

Comment: I installed Drupal using composer, but for some reason, _drush_ didn't seem to be installed or functional, so I began looking for documentation.
I opted to ignore option 2 (Drush Launcher) as it was marked optional and mentioned something about "listens for" which didn't give me the feeling it would last past a reboot.
Option 3 also did not work for me. Typing 'drush init' simply gave me back something like 'no such command or filename.' 
**Solution**: After much searching, I ended up having to set up a 'PATH export $home/something bla bla' thing in my .bashrc